# Gulp dependencies not waiting for git pull to finish

Tags: git, gulp

I need the task that has a dependency on my 'checkout' task to wait for the git pull to finish. Here's what I've tried, but it goes on to the following task without waiting for the checkout...

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'), git = require('gulp-git');

gulp.task('checkout', function() {
  return git.pull('origin', 'Devel', { cwd: './source' }, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      gutil.log(err);
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('lint', ['checkout'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./source/static.backyardfruit.com/js/backyardfruit/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a callback in the gulp task function. Here is the working code:

```
gulp.task('checkout', function(cb) {
  git.pull('origin', 'Devel', { cwd: './source' }, function(err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb();
  });
});

gulp.task('lint', ['checkout'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./source/static.backyardfruit.com/js/backyardfruit/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'));
});
```